# How to configure seed and urlfilter confg files in Apache Nutch

Tags: nutch

I would like to setup Nutch so that it goes through all `http://www.domain.com/classifieds/something/?pg=<page>` pages, for  goes from `1` to `200` and store the urls of the form `http://www.domain.com/classifieds/something/view/<number>/` where  is a ling number? Then, I would like print out all these urls in my terminal. I am using `Apache Nutch 1.9` and `Apache Solr 4.10.4`.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Nutch's urlnormalizer-regx plugin. Then, add the following to conf/regex-normalize.xml

```
<regex>
<pattern>(.*?)(pg=)\d{1,2})</pattern>
<substitution>$1/view/$3</substitution>
</regex>
```

This plugin allows you to alter urls based on regular expression. In the above example, I am matching your url into three parts. I then replace matched urls with the substitution patterns.

For the second problem you should enable indexer-dummy. This plugin will print data into text files.

If you are crawling a small site, then i will recommend using Scrapyy, it suits better your requirements

I hope that helps.